# Password hash Identity framework and salt

Tags: asp.net-identity, password-hash

I have been tasked with making sure that users cannot use previous passwords when changing their password. To that end I store the Hash of their password when the Identity framework hashes the password.

My question is how to compare the hash of the users newly selected password and the hash of their previously used password that I have saved?  I need to take into account the salt that the Identity framework is using.

UPDATE: I am using `appUserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(passwordToHash)` to hash the password but it creates a new hash each time (I assume it is because Identity framework is using a salt internally).

Comment: This aspnetcore identity or earlier version?

Comment: ASP.NET Identity v2.2

Comment: I would say override `UserManager<TUser, TKey>.UpdateAsync(TUser user)` and use a back-end history table. If a user is changing their password and it's one of the N passwords in the history, reject them with `IdentityResult.Failed("Cannot reuse password.")`.

Comment: I see what your saying Brad, but I wanted to create a separate class that would perform check that previous passwords were not used as well as other validations. My problem is that when I use `appUserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(passwordToHash)`. I get a different hash result every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current password hash for user is stored in table/column `AspNetUsers.PasswordHash`. This is also available through EF: `ApplicationDbContext.Users.PasswordHash`.

So you will need to create your own table that references user table and on every password change copy previous hash into your table.

Next step would be to verify that the new password does not match any of the old hashes. For that you need to use `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)`

Where `hashedPassword` would be a value from your table of historic hashes and `providedPassword` would be a new proposed password.

Comment: That makes sense. So I will not be able to hash the proposed password and then look to see if the hash exists in the table that holds previously hashed passwords. Looks like I will have to loop through all existing hashed passwords and compare each one.

Comment: Correct! This is the point of salting and hashing. Because salt is different every time, your resulting hash is going to be different every time. Hash the same password 10 times and you will get 10 different hash values. So yes, you will have to loop through every previous password and compare them via `VerifyHashedPassword`. Over time this might become a time-costly procedure, so I'd limit number of old hashes stored to 10-20.